# python3でjavascript内の変数内にある特定URLを検出

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

python3を使っています。
あるWEBページをスクレイピングして、javascript内の変数にm3u8のURLがあります。
その変数を抽出したいと思っています。

SeleniumやBeautifulSoupを使えばいいという記事は見つけましたが、どの変数に入っているか不明で、可能であればm3u8の文字列で検索かけれられたらと思っています。

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

[追加]
selenium経由でchromedriverを動かしました。

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
target_url = "http://<あるドメイン>"
driver.get(target_url)
```

でWEBページは取得できてjavascriptも動くようなのですが、javascriptで取得する変数にてm3u8の抽出方法がわかりません。
ご存知の方、是非ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでしょうか？

```
import re
import requests
url = ''
r = requests.get(url)
m = re.search('http.*?\.m3u8', r.text)
if m is not None:
    print('m3u8のURLは', m.group(0))
```

Comment: こちらのソースですと、Javascriptが動かなく固定的なページにおけるm3u8のURLを抽出するのみになるようです。